# iOS UDP: write to socket, then listen continuously

Tags: ios, swift, networking, udp

Setup: A device with a camera, an iPhone.

0. A phone connects to the device's wi-fi network. I figure out the gateway (in this case the device's IP) via `NWPathMonitor`.
1. I need to send "start" command to the device's IP and a specific port (say, `192.168.5.1:12345`). For that I establish [`NWConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwconnection) and send data when ready via [`connection.send(content:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwconnection/3003626-send).
2. The device then starts to continuously write in the connection's port. But using the Apple's [`Network`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network) lib I can only get the response once via [`connection.receiveMessage(completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwconnection/3020638-receivemessage) and such. I could have listened with [`NWListener`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwlistener), but in this use case I can't, since I have to write first and then listen for responses. And even when I create a Listener on the connection's port (from the phone's side) (with `allowLocalEndpointReuse`, if it matters), nothing happens.
3. When I'm done, I need to send "stop" in this very socket.

I experimented with some Mac tool called "PacketSender" and it receives all the responses alright, after I send a "start" command, until I send "stop". Is this a limitation of the `Network` lib, should I use some other tool, or do I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't want an NWListener since your app is initiating the communication. You should just call `recieveMessage` repeatedly. Can you show your code?

Comment: Omg, I thought there must be some other way. But yes, seems logical. I'm just calling `recieveMessage` again in it's callback until I need to stop. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add an answer for me to approve, or should I add the answer myself, with some code?